# pandas Aggregation using pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the data frame as the following snipping:

[image]

I want to convert it to be like the following:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
df2_SEX_AGE=df1.pivot(index='codprg', columns=['SEX','ETA'], values='counts')
```

but it raises the following error `KeyError: 'Level SEX not found'`

Comment: Sorry @jezrael but my question is completely different, I'm asking how to reshape my data frame without getting the mentioned error

Comment: @jezrael It's not due to misstype, I have the answer :)

Comment: @zipa could you please tell me the solution for my case ?!

Comment: Added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convert `MultiIndex` to `Index` use list comprehension with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for avoid error:

> Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

---

```
df2_SEX_AGE=df1.pivot_table(index='codprg', 
                            columns=['SEX','ETA'], 
                            values='counts',  
                            aggfunc='sum')
df2_SEX_AGE.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df2_SEX_AGE.columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work, when I run the first line of code it raises an error KeyError: 'Level SEX not found' @jezrael

Comment: @Peter - What is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: here is @jezrael   ['codprg', 'SEX', 'ETA', 'counts']

Comment: @Peter - so use `pivot_table` instead `pivot`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now it works, I really appreciate your help and support @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

This should sort you out:

```
(df1.assign(p=df['SEX'].astype(str) + df['ETA'].astype(str))
    .pivot(index='codprg', columns='p', values='counts'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work due to the following error
 `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshapede`

Comment: Then use `(df1.assign(p=df['SEX'].astype(str) + df['ETA'].astype(str))
    .pivot_table(index='codprg', columns='p', values='counts', aggfunc='sum'))`